# making gcc-10.5.0 while it is paused

Tags: gcc, gnu, gcc-warning, gcc10

I tried to install gcc-10.5.0 from source (without using sudo) based on the information provided in here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

However, after a while, it pauses without any error at the end. I have provided a file related to everything which has been printed out in screen, attached here.
I would be wondering if you could help me solve this issue.

```
libtool: compile:  /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include -minline-all-stringops -O2 -g -m32 -I . -c -fgo-pkgpath=cmd/go/internal/modget /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/modget/get.go -o cmd/go/internal/modget.o
/usr/bin/mkdir -p cmd/go/internal; files=`echo /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/test/cover.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/test/testflag.go bytes.gox cmd/go/internal/base.gox cmd/go/internal/cache.gox cmd/go/internal/cfg.gox cmd/go/internal/cmdflag.gox cmd/go/internal/load.gox cmd/go/internal/lockedfile.gox cmd/go/internal/modload.gox cmd/go/internal/str.gox cmd/go/internal/work.gox cmd/internal/test2json.gox crypto/sha256.gox errors.gox flag.gox fmt.gox go/build.gox io.gox io/ioutil.gox os/exec.gox os.gox path/filepath.gox path.gox regexp.gox sort.gox strconv.gox strings.gox sync.gox time.gox | sed -e 's/[^ ]*\.gox//g' -e 's/[^ ]*\.dep//'`; /bin/sh ./libtool --tag GO --mode=compile /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include     -minline-all-stringops  -O2 -g  -m32 -I . -c -fgo-pkgpath=`echo cmd/go/internal/test.lo | sed -e 's/.lo$//'` -static -o cmd/go/internal/test.lo $files
libtool: compile:  /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include -minline-all-stringops -O2 -g -m32 -I . -c -fgo-pkgpath=cmd/go/internal/test /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/test/cover.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/test/testflag.go -o cmd/go/internal/test.o
/usr/bin/mkdir -p cmd/go/internal; files=`echo /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/vet/vet.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/vet/vetflag.go bytes.gox cmd/go/internal/base.gox cmd/go/internal/cmdflag.gox cmd/go/internal/load.gox cmd/go/internal/modload.gox cmd/go/internal/str.gox cmd/go/internal/work.gox encoding/json.gox flag.gox fmt.gox log.gox os/exec.gox os.gox path/filepath.gox strings.gox | sed -e 's/[^ ]*\.gox//g' -e 's/[^ ]*\.dep//'`; /bin/sh ./libtool --tag GO --mode=compile /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include     -minline-all-stringops  -O2 -g  -m32 -I . -c -fgo-pkgpath=`echo cmd/go/internal/vet.lo | sed -e 's/.lo$//'` -static -o cmd/go/internal/vet.lo $files
libtool: compile:  /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include -minline-all-stringops -O2 -g -m32 -I . -c -fgo-pkgpath=cmd/go/internal/vet /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/vet/vet.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/vet/vetflag.go -o cmd/go/internal/vet.o
rm -f libgotool.a
ar cru libgotool.a  cmd/go/internal/auth.o cmd/go/internal/base.o cmd/go/internal/bug.o cmd/go/internal/cache.o cmd/go/internal/cfg.o cmd/go/internal/clean.o cmd/go/internal/cmdflag.o cmd/go/internal/doc.o cmd/go/internal/envcmd.o cmd/go/internal/fix.o cmd/go/internal/fmtcmd.o cmd/go/internal/generate.o cmd/go/internal/get.o cmd/go/internal/help.o cmd/go/internal/imports.o cmd/go/internal/list.o cmd/go/internal/load.o cmd/go/internal/lockedfile.o cmd/go/internal/lockedfile/internal/filelock.o cmd/go/internal/modcmd.o cmd/go/internal/modconv.o cmd/go/internal/modfetch.o cmd/go/internal/modfetch/codehost.o cmd/go/internal/modget.o cmd/go/internal/modinfo.o cmd/go/internal/modload.o cmd/go/internal/mvs.o cmd/go/internal/par.o cmd/go/internal/renameio.o cmd/go/internal/robustio.o cmd/go/internal/run.o cmd/go/internal/search.o cmd/go/internal/str.o cmd/go/internal/test.o cmd/go/internal/tool.o cmd/go/internal/txtar.o cmd/go/internal/version.o cmd/go/internal/vet.o cmd/go/internal/web.o cmd/go/internal/work.o cmd/internal/browser.o cmd/internal/buildid.o cmd/internal/diff.o cmd/internal/edit.o cmd/internal/objabi.o cmd/internal/sys.o cmd/internal/test2json.o golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519.o golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519.o golang.org/x/mod/internal/lazyregexp.o golang.org/x/mod/modfile.o golang.org/x/mod/module.o golang.org/x/mod/semver.o golang.org/x/mod/sumdb.o golang.org/x/mod/sumdb/dirhash.o golang.org/x/mod/sumdb/note.o golang.org/x/mod/sumdb/tlog.o golang.org/x/mod/zip.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/internal/analysisflags.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/internal/facts.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/asmdecl.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/assign.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/atomic.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/bools.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/buildtag.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/cgocall.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/composite.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/copylock.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/ctrlflow.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/errorsas.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/httpresponse.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/inspect.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/internal/analysisutil.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/loopclosure.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/lostcancel.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/nilfunc.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/pkgfact.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/printf.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/shift.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/stdmethods.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/structtag.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/tests.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/unmarshal.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/unreachable.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/unsafeptr.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/unusedresult.o golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/unitchecker.o golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil.o golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/inspector.o golang.org/x/tools/go/cfg.o golang.org/x/tools/go/types/objectpath.o golang.org/x/tools/go/types/typeutil.o golang.org/x/xerrors.o golang.org/x/xerrors/internal.o
ranlib libgotool.a
make[8]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/32/libgo'
make[7]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/32/libgo'
make[6]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/32/libgo'
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/gotools'
/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/.libs -o go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/go/alldocs.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/go/go11.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/go/main.go ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/libgotool.a
/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/.libs -o gofmt /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/doc.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/gofmt.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/internal.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/rewrite.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/simplify.go ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/libgotool.a
echo 'package main' > zdefaultcc.go.tmp
/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/.libs -o vet /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/vet/doc.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/vet/main.go ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/libgotool.a
/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/.libs -o buildid /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/buildid/buildid.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/buildid/doc.go ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/libgotool.a
/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/.libs -o test2json /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/test2json/main.go ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/libgotool.a
echo 'func defaultGCCGO(goos, goarch string) string { return "/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/bin/gccgo" }' >> zdefaultcc.go.tmp
echo 'func defaultCC(goos, goarch string) string { return "gcc" }' >> zdefaultcc.go.tmp
echo 'func defaultCXX(goos, goarch string) string { return "g++" }' >> zdefaultcc.go.tmp
echo 'const defaultPkgConfig = "pkg-config"' >> zdefaultcc.go.tmp
/bin/sh /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../move-if-change zdefaultcc.go.tmp zdefaultcc.go
echo timestamp > s-zdefaultcc
/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/gccgo -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/./gcc/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo -L ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/.libs -o cgo /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/ast.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/doc.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/gcc.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/godefs.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/main.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/out.go /usr/not-backed-up/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/cgo/util.go zdefaultcc.go ../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgo/libgotool.a
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir/gotools'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/not-backed-up/objdir'
```

I tried different versions, but the same problem happened to me.

Comment: What is the cpu and memory usage on the machine? What is the most active  process? Maybe, it is just working?

Comment: Almost zero for cpu and 2 G out of 32 G for RAM. I leave it for about four hours but it did not make any progress. I used  this command: make -j8.